# Heap’s algorithm wiki picture vs algorithm

Tags: heaps-algorithm

I’m trying to understand Heap’s algorithm from the Wikipedia page and I’m trying to compare the picture with the algorithm and I can’t seem to figure it out

[image]

this picture is from the wikipedia page

why would it switch the #1 and #2 first, shouldn’t it switch the #1 and #4 first?

I’m using java but this is just the code copied from Wikipedia, I understand that there is switching involved for the code in general

```
    if k = 1 then
        output(A)
    else
        // Generate permutations with kth unaltered
        // Initially k == length(A)
        generate(k - 1, A)

        // Generate permutations for kth swapped with each k-1 initial
        for i := 0; i < k-1; i += 1 do
            // Swap choice dependent on parity of k (even or odd)
            if k is even then
                swap(A[i], A[k-1]) // zero-indexed, the kth is at k-1
            else
                swap(A[0], A[k-1])
            end if
            generate(k - 1, A)

        end for
    end if
```

`k` is initially 4 so wouldn’t it switch A[0] and A[3] first?

Sorry in advance if this is a stupid question...

Answer (score 1):

When `k > 1`, the very first thing it does is recurse.  So, the calls go:

```
generate(4,A) calls
  generate(3,A) calls
    generate(2,A) calls
      generate(1,A) which prints A
      Now we do the processing for k==2.
      swap(0,1)
      generate(1,A) which prints the new A
      etc.
```

Comment: sorry if this is another stupid question, but what is generate(4,A), generate(3,A), generate(2,A), generate(1,A) then?

Comment: The original call is going to call `generate(4,A)`, right?  You have 4 things to swap, you're passing the array A.  The first thing that `generate` is going to do is call `generate(k-1,A)`.  Since k is 4, that results in `generate(3,A)`.

Comment: ok so that’s where the mysticalness comes from... they’re like dummivariables that keep track of everything, the mysticalness comes from how the algorithm is split up, and the generate(4,A), generate(3,A),generate(2,A),generate(1,A) appear to come out of nowhere... but really it’s a neat accounting trick with multiple moving parts

Comment: That's just how recursion works.  That's the basis of the concept.